# Add inputs dynamically when click on button in angular 4

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I would create a form with the possibility to add  inputs dynamically
I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256852/how-to-add-more-input-fields-using-a-button-angular-2-dynamic-forms) about the same problem in angular 2  but I can't make it working in my exemple

Here's my component **ts** file :

```
export class AjoutProjetComponent implements OnInit {
    isLinear = false;
    firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
    secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            pers: [this._formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])]
        });
    }
    createItem(): FormGroup {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required]
            poste: ['', Validators.required],

        });
    }
    addItem(): void {
        const control = < FormArray > this.secondFormGroup.controls['pers'];
        control.push(this.createItem());
    }

}
```

**then HTML file**

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Constituez votre équipe</ng-template>
        <div formArrayName="pers">
            <mat-form-field *ngFor="let control of secondFormGroup.controls.pers.controls; let i= index">
                <input matInput placeholder="Nom collaborateur" formControlName="name" required>
            </mat-form-field>

        </div>
    </form>
</mat-step>
        <div>{{secondFormGroup.value | json}}</div>
```

When I click in my favorite icon I get this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: control.push is not a function at AjoutProjetComponent.addItem
```

How can I make adding dynamically inputs working ?

**UPDATE**
I have updated my html code so that I could print two inputs but when I run my code I get this error now

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'pers -> name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not declare your `FormArray` properly. You use arrays only to initialize simple FormControls, not `FormGroups` or `FormControls`, change to :

```
this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        pers: this._formBuilder.array([this.createItem()]) // remove opening and closing brackets
    });
```

To see the inputs added dynamically to the html, you need to use an `ngFor` loop. I think you somewhat misunderstood the usage of `formArrayName`, which only adds context to the template to use with `FormArrays`. Try this:

```
<ng-container formArrayName="pers">
  <input placeholder="Address"  
    *ngFor="let control of secondFormGroup.controls.pers.controls"
    [formControl]="control.controls.name" required />
</ng-container>
```

And read more about `FormArrayName` directive [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName)

Comment: II don't get any error but , no input field is getting added to my page.

Comment: Thank you that's working , but I have a question: What is the difference between [formControl] and formControlName